# How can I concat these two rows into one column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table there are 2 rows with one common id and different values.

Ex :

```
ID Response
=============
1  one
1  two
2  three
3  four
```

How can I concat these two rows into one column.

```
select  
   case 
      when multiple then row1 + ',' + row2 
      else Response 
   end as response
from testtable
```

Expected output:

```
response
==========
one,two    
three 
four
```

SQL experts: how could I replace `row1 + ',' + row2` to make this query work ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Id, Stuff((Select ','+Response from TableName B where B.Id=A.Id for Xml Path('')),1,1,'') as Response from TableName A
group By Id;
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70027/2)

Comment: You could improve this answer by using value method: (... FOR XML...).value('.', '[N]VARCHAR(MAX)'). [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3db5/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table(id int,col1 varchar(20))
insert into @t values(1,'one'),(1, 'two'),(2, 'three'),(3, 'four')
select distinct a.id,
stuff((select ','+col1 from @t b where b.id=a.id for xml path('')),1,1,'')col1
from @t a
```